# Comparing homology of spaces of maps and spaces of basepoint-preserving maps

Tags: homotopy-theory

Is there a reference giving a method to compare the homology of $F(X,Y)$, the space of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$, with that of $F((X,x_0),(Y,y_0))$, the space of basepoint-preserving maps?

I'm assuming that all basepoints are non-degenerate, i.e. the inclusions $x_0 \to X$ and $y_0\to Y$ are cofibrations.  More specifically, I'm interested in the case where $X$ is a compact manifold and $Y$ is the classifying space of a compact Lie group.

I've done some preliminary work, writing the inclusion map $F((X,x_0),(Y,y_0))\to F(X,Y)$ as a fibration with fiber a loop space, but I feel I'm reinventing the wheel and someone has already done this much more efficiently that I am likely to do.

Comment: That inclusion map seems to be the fiber of a different fibration, $F_*(X,Y) \hookrightarrow F(X,Y) \to Y$, the last map being $f \mapsto f(x_0)$. Because this fibration has a section, the long exact sequence of homotopy groups splits, at least: $\pi_k F(X,Y) = \pi_k F_*(X,Y) \oplus \pi_k Y$ for $k > 1$. You also at least have the Serre spectral sequence. Because $H_* Y \to H_* F(X,Y)$ is injective, one may argue that all differentials on the bottom row are identically zero. But largely I don't know what one can say. I think (as often) things are much easier if $Y = S^1$.